# El bucle se pierde

Tags: c

hola buenas tengo un problema con un bucle que lee hasta el final de archivo pero se queda en la ultima parte del archivo y el bucle se queda en esa parte dando bueltas lo que produce un buffer dumped en C si alguien pudiera ayudar
muchas gracias
fd = fopen(filename, "r");

```
        do
        {

            byte = getline(&aux, &max_num, fd);
            printf("%s\n",aux);
            token = strtok(aux, " ");
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            printf("%s\n",token);
            strcpy(cell[cont].id, token);
            printf("%s",cell[cont].id);
            

            byte=getline(&aux, &max_num, fd);
            printf("%s\n",aux);
            token = strtok(aux, " ");
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            printf("%s\n",token);
            strcpy(cell[cont].addres, token);

            byte=getline(&aux, &max_num, fd);
            printf("%s\n",aux);
            token = strtok(aux, ":");
            token = strtok(NULL, ":");
            printf("%s\n",token);
            strcpy(cell[cont].essid, token);

            byte=getline(&aux, &max_num, fd);
            printf("%s\n",aux);
            token = strtok(aux, ":");
            token = strtok(NULL, ":");
            printf("%s\n",token);
            strcpy(cell[cont].mode, token);

            byte=getline(&aux, &max_num, fd);
            printf("%s\n",aux);
            token = strtok(aux, ":");
            token = strtok(NULL, ":");
            printf("%s\n",token);
            strcpy(cell[cont].channel, token);

            byte=getline(&aux, &max_num, fd);
            printf("%s\n",aux);
            token = strtok(aux, ":");
            token = strtok(NULL, ":");
            printf("%s\n",token);
            strcpy(cell[cont].encriptK, token);

            byte=getline(&aux, &max_num, fd);
            printf("%s\n",aux);
            token = strtok(aux, "=");
            token = strtok(NULL, "=");
            printf("%s\n",token);
            strcpy(cell[cont].quality, token);

            byte=getline(&aux, &max_num, fd);
            printf("%s\n",aux);
            token = strtok(aux, ":");
            token = strtok(NULL, ":");
            printf("%s\n",token);
            strcpy(cell[cont].frec, token);

            byte=getline(&aux, &max_num, fd);
            printf("%s\n",aux);
            token = strtok(aux, "=");
            token = strtok(NULL, "=");
            printf("%s\n",token);
            strcpy(cell[cont].signal, token);

            cont++;
        } while (!feof(fd));
        printf("conseguido\n");
        fclose(fd);
```

el archivo contiene celdas de un wifi donde tienen informacion de su id su addr su essid el canal etc pero cuando llega a la ultima linea del archivo este no termina el bucle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El flag `EOF` no se activa justo cuando se alcanza el final del archivo sino cuando se realiza la primera lectura no válida. Esto quiere decir que deberías verificar el estado del flag `EOF`, al menos, justo después de la primera lectura del bucle:

```
byte = getline(&aux, &max_num, fd);
if (feof(fd)) break; // <<--- check flag EOF

printf("%s\n",aux);
token = strtok(aux, " ");
token = strtok(NULL, " ");
printf("%s\n",token);
strcpy(cell[cont].id, token);
printf("%s",cell[cont].id);
```

Si ya luego quieres prever otras circunstancias anómalas, como que falten campos en el archivo, entonces ya tendrías que añadir el chequeo detrás de cada lectura que hagas.

Comment: muchisimas gracias porfiiiiiiiiiin muchas gracias en serio este programa me traia la cabeza loca durante hace varios dias muchas gracias otra vez

Comment: muchisimas gracias en serio menos mal

Comment: @Albertofelipe de nada, este portal existe justamente para eso